# How to grab number after a word or symbol in PHP?

Tags: php, function, numbers

I want to grab a text with PHP just like for an example, There is a data "The apple=10" and I want to grab **only the numbers** from the data which looks exactly like that. I mean, the number's place would be after 'equals'.

and my problem is that the number from the source can be 2 or 3 characters or on the other word it is inconstant.

please help me to solve them :)

Comment: Try some regex: http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php

Comment: Do you have more than just that text? or is it just "The apple=123"?

Comment: @RiggsFolly: I have tried to use substr() but the number that I want to grab is inconstant, and I am stuck on there, and that is as far as I've tried.

Comment: @SidiaStudios yes, the data Im working on is actually like this "Orange=10 | Apple=15 | Banana= 1" it is **exactly** the data I am working on and the problem I am facing is those numbers can be either hundreds, thousands, or tens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$string = "Apple=10 | Orange=3 | Banana=7";
$elements = explode("|", $string);
$values = array();
foreach($elements as $element)
{
    $element = trim($element);
    $val_array = explode("=", $element);
    $values[$val_array[0]] = $val_array[1];
}

var_dump($values);
```

Output:

```
array(3) { 
    ["Apple"]=> string(2) "10" 
    ["Orange"]=> string(1) "3" 
    ["Banana"]=> string(1) "7" 
}
```

Hope thats how you need it :)

Answer (score 0):

Well, php is a bit lazy about `int` conversion, so `12345blablabla` can be converted to `12345`:

```
$value = intval(substr($str, strpos($str, '=') + 1));
```

Of course, this is not the cleanest way but it is simple. If you want something cleaner, you could use a regexp:

```
preg_match ('#=([0-9]+)#', $str, $matches);
$value = intval($matches[1]) ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code:

```
$givenString= "The apple=10";    
$required_string = substr($givenString, strpos($givenString, "=") + 1);    
echo "output = ".$required_string ; // output = 10
```

Using [strpos()](http://php.net/strpos) function, you can *Find the position of the first occurrence of a substring in a string*
and [substr()](http://php.net/substr) function, Return part of a string.